# Problem with Twitter endpoint to post tweets

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a problem with a simple script to post tweets to Twitter.
I'm using the TwitterOAuth library made by Abraham. And i suddenly i can't post tweets.

With the endpoint **statuses/update** (which accessible for Free plan, what i have) i see the error: "You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: [https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product"](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product%22) with HTTPerrorcode 403.

When i take a look in the Twitter Developers docs, i see that the endpoint is changed to **/2/tweets**. When i use **/2/tweets**, it gives the HTTP-errorcode 404 (not found). I have alsto tried: **2/tweets**, **/tweets** and **tweets**. But it give all of them a 404 error.

What is the right endpoint to use in this script?

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

define('CONSUMER_KEY', '*********');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', '**************');

$access_token = "*****************";
$access_token_secret = "*********";

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token, $access_token_secret);
$connected = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
echo "<pre>".print_r($connected,true)."</pre>";


//echo "<pre>" . print_r($connection, true) . "</pre>";
$status = $connection->post("statuses/update", ["status" => "This is a test message."]);


//$status = $connection->post("tweets", ["status" => "This is a test message."]);


if ($connection->getLastHttpCode() == 200) {
    echo "It's okay! It's posted. Code 200 = OK! Yeah!";
} else {
    $code = $connection->getLastHttpCode();
    echo "HTTP-code is: " . $code;
    echo 'Error: ' . $status->errors[0]->message;
    print_r($status);
}
?>
```